# TypeScript classes and interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript code:-

```
    export class Parent {
    name: string;
    details: Details = {};
}

export interface Details {
    age?: number;
    address?: Address};
}

export interface Address {
    address1: string;
    address2: string;
}
```

Then I can reference this code to set some values:-

```
var myOptions = new HSCIC.Visualisation.Services.Parent();

myOptions.name = "Chris";
myOptions.details.age = 25;
myOptions.details.address.address1 = "10 The Lane";
```

The first two setters are working fine but I get a 'Cannot set property 'address1' of 'undefined'.

If I can set the age property from Details, then why can't I set the address1 property of Address, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Because you wrote:

```
address?: Address};
```

But for the code to be valid, it should be:

```
address?: Address = {address1: null, address2: null};
```

You need to assign a value to address, just like you did in `details: Details = {};`, or it will be undefined. To do it this way, Details would need to be defined as a class, not an interface. Writing `: Address` does not instantiate a new class, it only specifies the type. Alternatively, you can make address1 and 2 optional like you did address, using `?`, and then just write `address?: Address = {};`

If you don't want to define Details as a class, you could write `details: Details = {address:{}};` under Parent.

Comment: I have made address1 and address2 optional but it's not happy about the line:

address?: Address = {};

Comment: Perfect, that's it. I didn't want to make it a class.